# Excel Automated Data Retrieval From Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I'm pretty new to excel formulas and got almost no experience with VBA. But I've come across with a problem that I need to solve.

***So the scenario goes like this.***

I've got two workbooks and I need to retrieve data to one workbook from another if the condition for a cell value is met. Let me explain with an example.

(C for columns, R for rows, x for random numbers)

I've got Workbook A as shown below:

[image]

And Workbook B with the same structure

***So what I'm trying to achieve here is:***

**When I change/insert values in Workbook A, C3Rx there will be a conditional mechanism that will check for the value.
Let's say if C3R1's value is "1" on Workbook A, it should fill C1R1, C2R1 and C3R1 on Workbook B accordingly.
If the value is not "1", it just should keep scanning the Workbook A, C3 and when it meets the conditional requirement (C3Rx having the value of "1"), it should write it in and go to the next row (C1R(x+1)). Follow the procedure again and again. Scanning all values in Workbook A.**

I've tried to make it work using VLOOKUP and some other functions together but it doesn't suit really well with my case. It works with spaces when the value does not meet the condition and also, I need to fill all the cells on C1 with the formula till the end. (considering I don't know how long it may go, that's not really a solution for me)

I think it's achievable with Macros but like I've said, I don't have much experience with VBA.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly get what you mean.
Anyway below I am guessing on what you mean.

Below is what contains in Workbook-A sheet1 column A to C 
[image]

Below is what contains in Workbook-B sheet1 column A to C 
[image]

With the first condition that Workbook-A and Workbook-B are arlready open.... below is Workbook-A sheet1 where cell C4 and C7 fill with 1 value,
and after the button is clicked :
1. Cell A4 to C4 value in Workbook-A Sheet1 become the value of cell A4 to C4 value in Workbook-B Sheet1. 
2. Cell A7 to C7 value in Workbook-A Sheet1 become the value of cell A7 to C7 value in Workbook-B Sheet1

[image]

Button1 is assign to a macro like this :

```
Sub test()
Set wbA = Workbooks("Test-A.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wbB = Workbooks("Test-B.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = wbA.Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In Rng
If cell.Value = 1 Then
r = cell.Row
wbA.Range("A" & r, "C" & r).Value = wbB.Range("A" & r, "C" & r).Value
'wbA.Range("A" & r, "C" & r).Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The code will look to each value in column C (starts from row 2) in Workbook-A sheet1.
If the code find the value is 1 in row X of column C, then it copy row X of column A to C in Workbook-B sheet1.

That's if I'm not mistaken on what you mean.

Comment: That's close to what I mean. 
The only difference is, I would like to copy the whole row which has the matching value to Workbook B and achieving this without a button click (automatically when Workbook B is launched)

Comment: Do you mean the code is in Workbook-B and when the Workbook-B is open, it will also open Workbook-A then check if there is a value "1" in Workbook-A column C ? You wrote : "_I would like to copy the whole row which has the matching value to Workbook B"_ . So do you mean the code then will copy the row X on column A to C of Workbook-A then paste it to the row X on column A to C of Workbook-B ?

Comment: Basically yea. Not necessarily open Workbook A though. I'm not really familiar with how macros/formulas behave when the source workbook is closed. Both files are on different paths in a server in my company's network. So when I type in the correct value on Workbook A, Column C, it should insert that row (all/specified columns) to Workbook B's next empty row. If Column C does not have the right value on that row, it should skip it. That's basically it.

Comment: Maybe an example would help
Let's say I've got a main Workbook (Workbook A) and I keep the employee's info in it (Columns: emp_id, full_name, branch_location).
There are different workbooks for every branch named after the cities (Workbook B) (ex; Madrid.xlsx) on different paths and has the info of employees work at only that branch.
So when I type in Madrid on branch_location column in a certain row in Workbook A, it should transfer the whole row to next empty row in Madrid.xlsx (Workbook B), if I type in London, it should skip that row. So the macro will run on Workbook B.

Comment: @WezzWestbrook, sorry I'm not clear with your sentence "_when I type in Madrid on branch_location column in a certain row in Workbook A_". Do you mean when you type a word "Madrid" ? Or when you type a number "1" ON a word "Madrid" which already as a value in row X of column branch_location? I'm sorry I was wrong, because I thought the "beginning" condition of workbook-A and workbook-B is just like the 1st image and the 2nd image in my post. So after you type "1" in row X col3 wb-A, you want to get the value in col1 to col3 **row X wb-B** overwrite the value in col1 to col3 **row X of wb-A**.

Comment: I think it will be more clear if you give a sample screen shot of the "beginning" condition of your wb-A and wb-B and the screen shot of the result you want to achieve. And if possible, maybe you can explain what you want to do, 
for example "I want to ADD data to wb-B from the value in wb-A" 
or "I want to SEE the information of wb-B in wb-A".
or maybe "I want to CORRECT the value in wb-A based on the value in wb-B", etc. Thanks.

Comment: Would it make any difference if the C column cell is empty or not at the beginning? I mean no matter what, when I type in a value on the cell and if it meets the conditions I want. It should add the data to Wb-B from the value in Wb-A. The source document will be Workbook A and if the cell value is "Madrid" OR if I change it to Madrid, it will copy the information for all columns in that row to "Madrid.xlsx". If the cell is empty, it'll copy the data WHEN I type in "Madrid". Sorry if this is still not clear. I'm going to post a sample as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, don't understand "_when I type in a value on the cell and if it meets the conditions I want_". Coz what I thought is : if you type **number "1"** in 3rd Col row  X wb-A ---> then it **meet the condition for the code to do something**  which in your case is to copy row X from col-1 to col-3 of wb-A  then paste to the last empty row in col-1 of wb-B. So, the condition which trigger the code to do the copy paste is when the code find value "1" in col-3 whatever row of wb-A. If the next row value is not "1", the code skip it then continue to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that both workbooks already open.

Below is the beginning look of wb-A right after it's open :
[image]

Below is the beginning look of wb-B right after it's open :
[image]

Back to wb-A, after you examined the data, you decided that id-003 branch location is not London, but Madrid. So you type number 1 in the third column id-003 row. WB-A now look like this :
[image]

And what you expect is, if the code find any row in the third column of wb-A with value "1", then the code have to copy all the three columns of id-003 row then paste it to the last blank row in the emp_id column of wb-B. So, wb-B look like this :
[image]

Here is the code which has to be in wb-A module :

```
Sub test()
Set wbA = Workbooks("Test-A.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wbB = Workbooks("Test-B.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = wbA.Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In Rng
If cell.Value = 1 Then
Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, -2)).Copy Destination:= _
wbB.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Again, above is just my guessing because I'm still not clear what you want and how is the situation.

Comment: "Madrid" and "1" was just examples. Doesn't matter what I type in as long as it meets the requirements. "Madrid" was just an example. To put it simply, I want the row copied from Wb-A to Wb-B when I type in the right value on Wb-A

Comment: You wrote : _"I want the row copied from Wb-A to Wb-B when I type in **the right value** on Wb-A"_. So how the code know that you type "the right value" ?. Or do you mean :  _"whenever and whatever I type in row X col-3 sheet1 wb-A"_ it triggers the code to do the copy the row I typed in, from col-1 to col-3 to the last blank row of col-1 on wb-B sheet1.? This need worksheet_selectionchange event.